# ADO sql Where clause for Access Null

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado

In Access I can apply Where Nz([Fieldname])= 7 and have the query work. However I am using an ADO connection to Access and the Nz function is not available. I have tried various combinations using IsNull but without success. Can anyone give me a working solution?

Comment: Provide the fill SQL statement

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the dbo schema to the function; e.g., dbo.Nz()?

Comment: Apologies, I did not understand this advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well-known problem. Instead of `NZ()` use the Access `IIF()` function:

```
iif ( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false )
```

like, for example, pertinent to your case (assuming the Fieldname Data Type is int):

```
WHERE (iif (([Fieldname] Is Null), 0, [Fieldname])=7)
```

If DataType is Text, then use the following syntax:

```
WHERE (iif (([Fieldname] Is Null), '0', [Fieldname])='7')
```

This will resolve the issue. 
Regards,

Comment: After trying I get 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

Comment: My full sql is SELECT tblTest.Title, tblTest.Mode
FROM tblTest
WHERE (((tblTest.Title) Like '*white christmas*') AND ((IIf(([tblTest.Mode] Is Null),0,[tblTest.Mode]))=7))
ORDER BY CDate([Date Entered]);

Comment: Still no luck after more tests./ Now just SELECT *
FROM tblTest
Where (IIf (([Mode] Is Null),0,[Mode])='7') is still failing with Data Type Mismatch. Field Mode is text. Any more ideas Alex ?

Comment: See the amended answer. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `[Fieldname]=7` as the condition in your `WHERE` clause?

If you don't specify a second argument to `Nz`, it will return an `Empty` value (equivalent to an empty string or the number zero) when the first argument is `Null`.  So, if `[Fieldname]` is `Null`, the condition `Nz([Fieldname])=7` will evaluate to `False` and the row will be excluded.

Similarly, if `[Fieldname]` is `Null`, the condition `[Fieldname]=7` will evaluate to `Null` and the row will be excluded.

Using `[Fieldname]=7` might also allow an index (if any) on `Fieldname` to be used to improve the performance of the query, whereas `Nz([Fieldname])=7` might not.

Comment: My fault. The error was hiding that I actually wanted <>7. Alex's WHERE is now oK, but thank you for nice details. Regards, K.

Comment: Good luck with your project! Best regards,